# Changing DNS server but not ip address - any downtime?

Tags: dns, ip-address

We are planning on moving our DNS records from our hosting provider to our registrar, but all of the endpoints will be the same.

Will there be any downtime (I'm hoping no since both will point to the same IP addresses)?

Any best practices to minimize any issues?

Thanks!

Comment: This seems to be a question for `serverfault`, but I'd say that if you have redundancy on the servers, do one node at a time just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't have any issues. In any case, I'd change the TTL to something short (say 5 minutes), wait till the current TTL expires (if the TTL was 1 day, wait a day) and then make the move. This way, you'd be able to quickly recover from any potential issues during the migration with a very low downtime.

Once the migration is complete, verify things work (DNS queries from multiple locations, etc.) or wait a few days to hear of any issues. You can then reset the TTL to something larger.